# How to copy a file from source to a destination and recreate the folder structure

Tags: copy, xcopy, robocopy

I have some files which needs to be copied through deployment process often to a destination. This is my folder folder structure:

SOURCE:

```
c:\
   folder1
          sub1
              subsub1
                     file1
                     file2
```

I need something where i can tell my "script" something like this

`mycopy c:\folder1\sub1\subsub1\file1 h:\`

That means that i **dont want** to

- check if folder structure exist
- provide on bot sides the complete structure for each file on destination side

I **want** to

- provide the full path and filename on source side
- create folder structure if not exist
- overwrite file if exist

How can i achieve this?

Comment: Has noone an idea how to do this or it this maybe impossible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok it works like this:

You can use Robocopy for this task. Thanks you Rick716 for this direction. I am not marking it as answer cause it is only a direction not the solution.

Lets Assume that we have the following source folder structure:

```
N:\source\a1\b1\c1\d1\e1\f1
```

and we want to recreate the hole structure under `n:\source` within `h:\destination`. Then we have to use Robocopy in this way:

```
robocopy N:\source h:\destination /e
```

The option `/e` will create the folder structure even create empty folders. Additionally you can append the files which should be copied. For example

```
file.txt
*.jpg
*.bkp
```

etc. But these files will be even copied when they exist **somewhere** within the folder strcuture! For example you have the file n:\source\a1\file.txt and the file n:\source\a1\b1\c1\file.txt then both will be copied by using

```
robocopy N:\source h:\destination file.txt /e
```

Answer (score 0):

See the robocopy help page on MS Technet

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc733145%28v=ws.11%29.aspx

In your case you would do something like

```
robocopy c:\folder1\sub1\subsub1  h:\  file1  <options ...>
```

Notice that the first two parameters are the source and dest *paths* only, with no filename at the end

Read the linked help page and test on your desktop ...